# Get domain from within linked script CFM file

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm trying to develop a 1-page mini-app that can be deployed with 2 lines of code.

```
<div id="app_wrapper"></div> 
<script src="http://mydomain.com/js/loader.cfm?id=12"></script>
```

This would be on the different domain, let's call it http://theirdomain.com/client.html

Then inside the loader file, I check to see if the domain is the same as one of those on the settings, so non-payers can't just copy those 2 lines and run this mini-app on their site without paying.

```
<cfset refererDomain = reReplace(CGI.SERVER_NAME,"^\w+://([^\/:]+)[\w\W]*$","\1","one") />
<cfif (refererDomain neq "") and (refererDomain eq GetWBSettings.vchrDomain1 or refererDomain eq GetWBSettings.vchrDomain2 or refererDomain eq GetWBSettings.vchrDomain3 or 
refererDomain eq GetWBSettings.vchrDomain4 or refererDomain eq GetWBSettings.vchrDomain5) and GetWBSettings.blnActive eq 1>
```

Where GetWBSettings.vchrDomain1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are the authorized domains (They are allowed up to 5 domains per account) and GetWBSettings.blnActive is a boolean whether the client is active.

I have run into a problem and I cannot figure out how to solve it. CGI.SERVER_NAME is outputting http://mydomain.com rather than http://theirdomain.com. I also tried CGI.HTTP_REFERRER, but that, in this case, is outputing an empty string.

Another thing I was thinking about, that since I'm in a script, maybe I can somehow get it with javascript's location.host and somehow pass it on to my cfif statement

I'm using Coldfusion 9

Answer (score 3):

`<script src="http://mydomain.com/js/loader.cfm?id=12"></script>`

The CFM is running on you your domain, so CGI.SERVER_NAME is your own server. CGI.HTTP_REFERRER can be spoofed, so it's not reliable anyway.

You might consider instead giving them a JavaScript file that they run on their site that makes a request to an API on your site. The API would require an authentication token and return the content that your CFM currently returns.

You could implement it in a similar manner as this:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#SimpleaccessusingtheAPIkey

`gapi.client.setApiKey(YOUR API KEY);`

You could then include data from that server in your request to your API, which may help you keep non-paying requests from accessing your API with copied API keys.